# Combine Two Slick Futures and then execute them together

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have written this code and I am trying to combine two futures obtained from separate SQL operations.

```
package com.example

import tables._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    try {
      val people = TableQuery[Persons]
      val setupAction : DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
        people.schema.create
        )
      val setupFuture : Future[Unit] = db.run(setupAction)

      val populateAction: DBIO[Option[Int]] = people ++= Seq(
          (1, "test1", "user1"),
          (2, "test2", "user2"),
          (3, "test3", "user3"),
          (4, "test4", "user4")
        )

      val populateFuture : Future[Option[Int]] = db.run(populateAction)

      val combinedFuture : Future[Option[Int]] = setupFuture >> populateFuture

      val r = combinedFuture.flatMap { results =>
        results.foreach(x => println(s"Number of rows inserted $x"))
      }
      Await.result(r, Duration.Inf)
    } 
    finally db.close
  }
}
```

But I get an error when I try to compile this code

```
[error] /Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest2/src/main/scala/Hello.scala:29: 
value >> is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
[error]       val combinedFuture : Future[Option[Int]] = setupFuture >>
populateFuture
[error]                                                              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The same code works, If I nest the populateFuture inside the map function of the setupFuture. But I don't want to write nested code because it will become very messy once there are more steps to do.

So I need a way to combine all futures into a single future and then execute it.

Edit:: I also tried combining the two actions

```
  val combinedAction = setupAction.andThen(populateAction)

  val fut1 = combinedAction.map{result =>
    result.foreach{x =>println(s"number or rows inserted $x")}
  }
  Await.result(fut1, Duration.Inf)
```

but got error

```
/Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest/src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]
[error]  required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[Unit],?]
[error]       val combinedAction = setupAction.andThen(populateAction)
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 26, 2015 3:50:51 PM
Mohitas-MBP:SlickTest abhi$
```

Comment: You can use `for` comphersion or `flatMap` to compose two future. `val combied = setupFuture.flatMap(_ => populateFuture)`, e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction, `andThen()` is what you are looking for:

```
val combinedAction = setupAction.andThen(populateAction)
val results = db.run(combinedAction)
```

`populateAction` will only run after `setupAction` completed successfully. This is crucial in your case since slick is fully non-blocking. The code you have now will cause problems at runtime. Both actions in your code will run  asynchronously at the same time. There is no way to determine which action is executed first. But because `populateAction` depends on `setupAction`, you must ensure `setupAction` is executed first. Therefore use `andThen`.

Comment: does not work. here is the error I got `error] /Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest2/src/main/scala/Hello.scala:29: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]
[error]  required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[Unit],?]
[error]       val combinedFuture : Future[Option[Int]] = setupFuture.andThen(populateFuture)`

Comment: Combine the actions direclty using `andThen`, not the results. Then execute the combined action on your database to get the results.

Comment: I still get a compilation error when I try to combine the two actions. `error] /Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest/src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]]
[error]  required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[Unit],?]
[error]       val combinedAction = setupAction.andThen(dataLoadAction)
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
`

Comment: This code finally worked for me `val action1 = people.schema.create
    val action2 = people ++= Seq(createList(numRows) : _* )
    val combined = db.run(action1 andThen action2)`